# Trouble connecting to my database with entity framework c# web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a LogContext Model :

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace Logging.Models
{
    public class LogContext : DbContext
    {
        // You can add custom code to this file. Changes will not be overwritten.
        // 
        // If you want Entity Framework to drop and regenerate your database
        // automatically whenever you change your model schema, add the following
        // code to the Application_Start method in your Global.asax file.
        // Note: this will destroy and re-create your database with every model change.
        // 
        // System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<Logging.Models.ProductContext>());

        public LogContext() : base("name=LogContext")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<LogContext>(null);
        }

        public DbSet<Log> Logs { get; set; }




    }
}
```

but when I try to reference the Logs in my other LogContext class under App_code I'm getting an error trying to reference the context.Logs.Load();
"cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name"

How do I reference and render all the rows in my table? What am i doing wrong? 
Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Logging.Controllers;
using Logging.Models;

namespace Logging
{
    public class LogContext : IDisposable
    {
        private static readonly List<Log> Logs = new List<Log>();

        static LogContext()
        {
            using (var context = new LogContext())
            {
                **context.Logs.Load();**
            }
            //Logs.Add(new Log() { Id = 1, LoggerName = "TESTSYS1", InnerException = "InnerException", LogText = "LogText", ThreadID = 1, StackTrace = "Stack Trace", eLevel = "INFO" });
            //Logs.Add(new Log() { Id = 2, LoggerName = "TESTSYS2", InnerException = "InnerException", LogText = "LogText", ThreadID = 2, StackTrace = "Stack Trace", eLevel = "ERROR" });
            //Logs.Add(new Log() { Id = 3, LoggerName = "TESTSYS3", InnerException = "InnerException", LogText = "LogText", ThreadID = 3, StackTrace = "Stack Trace", eLevel = "WARN" });
        }
        void IDisposable.Dispose()
        {

        }


        public void GetLoggies()
        {
            using (var context = new LogContext())
            {
                foreach (var log in context.GetLogs())
                {
                    Logs.Add(log);

                }
            }
        }

        public Log GetLog(int id)
        {
            var log = Logs.Find(p => p.Id == id);
            return log;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Log> GetLogs()
        {
            return LogContext.Logs;
        }

        public Log AddLog(Log p)
        {
            Logs.Add(p);
            return p;
        }

        public void Delete(int id)
        {
            var product = Logs.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
            if (product != null)
            {
                Logs.Remove(product);
            }
        }

        public bool Update(int id, Log log)
        {
            Log rLog = Logs.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
            if (rLog != null)
            {
                rLog = log;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is frankly very bad design.

1. Your class here has the same name as your context and also has a member with the same name as a member on your context, i.e. `Logs`. This is a case study in how intelligent the compiler is, in that the only reason the whole thing doesn't explode, is because it's able to make some sense out of which you want in which place, given context. Still, it might guess wrong, and *you* will certainly get confused at some point. If you insist on maintaining it this way, you should fully-qualify all uses of your actual context class, i.e. `new Namespace.To.LogContext()`, so the compiler isn't just guessing.
2. Using `using` around a context is a *hugely* bad idea. A context instance should ideally be request-scoped. Among other things, the context employs change tracking, and when you start passing entities between different context instances, you're going to run headlong into a brick wall. Instead, you should inject your context into this class and save it as a field on the class.
3. Implementing `IDisposable` is not something you should do lightly. There's a very particular way it needs to be implemented or you're actually causing more harm than good.

   ```
   public class Base: IDisposable
   {
       private bool disposed = false;

       //Implement IDisposable.
       public void Dispose()
       {
           Dispose(true);
           GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
       }

       protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
       {
           if (!disposed)
           {
               if (disposing)
               {
                   // Free other state (managed objects).
               }
               // Free your own state (unmanaged objects).
               // Set large fields to null.
               disposed = true;
           }
       }

       // Use C# destructor syntax for finalization code.
       ~Base()
       {
           // Simply call Dispose(false).
           Dispose (false);
       }
   }
   ```

   See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.100).aspx

   However, if you inject your context, this class will no longer own the context, and therefore wouldn't need to even implement `IDisposable`. And, for the love of everything good and holy, don't implement `IDisposable` when you're injecting dependencies. I see far too many developers do this and end up with strange bugs because resources are being disposed incorrectly.
4. Finally, just throw this class away completely. What you're essentially trying to create here (incorrectly) is a repository, and you don't need that. Entity Framework already implements the repository and unit of work patterns. As you can see from your methods here, all you're doing is basically proxying from your method to a nearly equivalent method on the `DbSet`. You're buying yourself nothing but just an additional layer that now has to be maintained, more entropy for your application code, and technical debt. For a more detail description of why this is the wrong approach see: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/220126/65618

Comment: ok I threw away the LogContext class under App_code, and I regenerated the methods from the controller and now I have only one LogContext class under the Models with methods that look like this:  
                internal Log GetLog(int id)
  {
   throw new NotImplementedException();
  }

Comment: How do I "inject" my context?

Comment: Don't tell me everything I'm doing is crap then leave me without a solution

Comment: Seriously? You know I actually have a paying job as well, right? Just because I didn't reply immediately is no cause to go off the handle, and honestly doesn't engender much desire to actually help you with a damn thing. However, even if was so inclined, you haven't provide any new "problem". After you made those changes, are you experiencing the same issue, a different issue, what exactly? As far as injecting your context goes, pick any DI container of your choice and familiarize yourself with the documentation. I personally like Ninject, but there's many others.

Comment: How many third party products do I need to install to replace what used to be a simple sql statement?

Comment: Enough to get the job done. It's not about replacing a simple SQL statement; it's about building an application in a best practice way.

Comment: Truth is, I have no idea what I'm doing, I tried to find a "simple" example of a Web Api but nothing is simple and every example I find leads me into a complex jungle of crazy stuff, all I want to do is render an api to read, write, delete and update records from one table in a database

Comment: That's because it is in fact all complex. Don't expect to just hack away for 5 minutes and have a workable solution when you've never done it before. Take the time to read the documentation. Maybe checkout a video or two on Pluralsight. Pay the $29 for a month and dig in. You need to learn to walk before you can run. Just take it a piece at at time, and keep working until you're there. Just don't expect it to be quick and easy because it won't and never will be.

Comment: I've done all that, I've been working on this for weeks now

Comment: Have just a litte bit of humanity and sympathy and try to answer my relevant questions instead of insulting me

Comment: so If i just put DbSet it comes loaded with methods like Get and Put and Delete?

Comment: Basically. To get you can use `Where` to filter, `Single`, `First`, `Find`, etc. to get a single item. To create, you literally just `Add` an item to the set and to delete, you literally just `Remove` an item from the set, just as with any other list-style instance.

Comment: Thanks for leading me in the right direction Chris.